# Given two negligible functions f(x) and g(x), is f(x)/g(x) negligible?

Tags: analysis, functions

My thought is that since a negligible function by definition is smaller than the inverse of any polynomial p(x), the quotient of f(x) and g(x) must be smaller than 1, and hence negligible.

Is this correct? How could I put this more formally?

Comment: I don't know what a "negligible function" is, but if $f=g$, then $f/g$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $f(x)=g(x)$. The quotient is 1.

Comment: Thank you. So how could I prove that the quotient of negligible functions is non-negligible?

Comment: By giving an example.

Comment: @J.Doe Quotient of negligible functions can be either negligible or non-negligible.